# Using a CSR Matrix in a multivariate random forest classification model

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am trying to utilize a CSR matrix as a variable to enhance my model. This matrix is derived from analyzing tf-idf metrics from string values in a pandas dataframe.

The series that the CSR matrix is derived from has 7325 records. After the CSR Matrix is generated it has a shape of (7325, 4927). I am not clear on the matrix format or what that 4927 represents.

But basically I am trying to use the matrix as 1 variable in a multivariate random forest classification model. I have tried converting the matrix to a dataframe, and then adding the martix dataframe and 2 other series' to create a new dataframe representing all my variable to plug into the model.

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(matrix), df['var1'], df['var2'])
```

but my dataframe is crazy. The matrix data isn't in the table. Furthermore Var 2 becomes the x-axis and var 1 is the y-axis. This does not happen if I just join the var 1 and var 2 series in a separate dataframe.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I can convert the matrix to a dataframe with a shape of (7325,1) just fine by

```
pd.DataFrame(matrix)
```

The shape of each of the other series' are (7325,). I don't know if this has something to do with it.

I generate the matrix via a tf-idf analysis of a string variable of parcel owner names. It involves tokenizing the string varibale and assigning values to every element in the string. I am able to pass the CSR matrix directly to sklearn RandomForestClassifier model and it works fine. I am now trying to add variables to the model:

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer


stemmer =PorterStemmer()
df['String_variable']=df['String_variable'].apply(lambda x: [stemmer.stem(y) for y in x])

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
counts = count_vect.fit_transform(df['String_variable'])

transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(counts)

matrix=transformer.transform(counts)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5eDS.png
```

Comment: How is that `csr` matrix generated?  You can't just pass it to `DataFrame`.  `matrix.A`, the dense equivalent might work in `DataFrame`, though it will produce a frame with 7000 rows and 5000 columns.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I updated the original post. I don't know if that's what I am after. Basically i am able to pass the CSR matrix directly to the model and it works fine. But I am trying to add two other variables into the model.

Answer (score 0):

Per hpaulj's comments I converted the matrix to a pandas dataframe via .todense().

```
x=pd.DataFrame(matrix.todense())

x['Var1']=df['Var1']
x['Var2']=df['Var2']
```

I was then able to plug it directly into the model trainer.